# Cloning whole reop with GIT-TFS is not working properly

Tags: git-tfs

I want wo migrate my TFS repo to GIT. After some research I found GIT-TFS. But I have some trouble with it. When I try to clone my repo from TFS I don't get all the content. The command I use is:

```
git-tfs clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/Collection $/my_project
```

After this the programm is running for some hours, because I have a very long history to save. There are no errors at the end but some folders are missing in the new git repo.

Has anybody else encountered same issues? Or am I using the tool wrong? Are there any restrictions about repository size?

Comment: Did you try `git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/Collection $/my_project . --branches=all
` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with some (big) files it seems to be a problem with the file size. According to the error the problem was that the filesize is bigger than an Int32.

```
Filesize: 2.878.003.200 byte
```

An Integer cannot represent that high number and an error is thrown. After ignoring this file from the checkout everything works fine.

I leave this as an answer here, even if I highly doubt that someone else have such big files in his repository.